# Как добавить кнопку для копирования содержимого в QGridLayout?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside2, сигналы-слоты, qpushbutton

Задача - взять из *SQL* базы определённый текст, и внести его в `QGridLayout` как кнопку, при нажатии на которую текст бы копировался.

Я испробовал метод (он уже встроен в код )

> button = QPushButton('Copy Text')
>
> self.grid.addWidget(button)

Проблема начинается со связкой сигнала.
Метод по типу **self.button.clicked.connect(self.Функция Копирования)** не работает, если вставить его в `Widget` class, и это в общем-то понятно.
Но если вставить связку сигнала в `MyWindow` class, то вылезет ошибка о том , что не найдена кнопка "button", т.к. естественно она создавалась в другом классе.

Что можно сделать? Может быть не стоило создавать кнопку в `Widget` class? А если и стоило, то как поймать сигнал от этой кнопки в основном классе, чтобы суметь отреагировать и скопировать нужный текст?

```
import sys
import requests
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, urls):
        super().__init__()

        self.grid = QGridLayout(self)

        buttons = QPushButton('Text Copy')

        for i, url in enumerate(urls):
            lbl = QLabel()
            image = QImage()
            image.loadFromData(requests.get(url,headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}).content)

            if i == 0:
                lbl.setPixmap(QPixmap(image).scaled(210, 210))
                self.grid.addWidget(lbl, i + 1, 0, 4, 1)
                self.grid.addWidget(buttons)
            else:
                lbl.setPixmap(QPixmap(image).scaled(70, 70))
                self.grid.addWidget(lbl, i, 1, 1, 1)


class ListWidget(QListWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ListWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setEditTriggers(self.NoEditTriggers)
        self.setFlow(self.LeftToRight)
        self.setWrapping(True)
        self.setResizeMode(self.Adjust)
        self.setSpacing(10)
        # Резиновая лента (для эффекта выбора рамки)
        self._rubberPos = None
        self._rubberBand = QRubberBand(QRubberBand.Rectangle, self)

    def makeItem(self, lb):
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(self)
        item.setSizeHint(QtCore.QSize(300, 300))
        self.setItemWidget(item, lb)


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('ListWidget')
        self.resize(1100, 670)
        self.show()

        self.listWidget = ListWidget()

        # кнопка
        self.push_button = QPushButton('del 0 item')

        box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        # добавляем кнопку
        box.addWidget(self.push_button)

        box.addWidget(self.listWidget)

        self.urls = [
            "https://img.icons8.com/ios/452/phone.png",
            "https://img.icons8.com/ios/452/phone.png",
            "http://www.google.com/favicon.ico",
            "https://www.imgonline.com.ua/examples/random-pixels-wallpaper-big.jpg",
            "https://laguna-akul.ru/upload/003/u379/f4/61/8f68d93a.jpg",
        ]

        num = 5
        for i in range(num):
            art = Widget(self.urls)
            self.listWidget.makeItem(art)
            QApplication.processEvents()
        # связываем сигнал нажатия на кнопку с методом
        self.push_button.clicked.connect(self._on_push_button_clicked)

    # метод-обработчик кнопки
    def _on_push_button_clicked(self):
        # takeItem удаляет итем с виджетом из списка и возвращает его
        removed = self.listWidget.takeItem(0)
        print(removed)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
import requests
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, urls, num):
        super().__init__()

        self.grid = QGridLayout(self)
        text = f'Text Copy {num}'
        self.buttons = QPushButton(text)              
        self.buttons.clicked.connect(lambda ch, text=text: self.onButton(text))     # +++

        for i, url in enumerate(urls):
            lbl = QLabel()
            image = QImage()
            image.loadFromData(requests.get(url,headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}).content)

            if i == 0:
                lbl.setPixmap(QPixmap(image).scaled(210, 210))
                self.grid.addWidget(lbl, i + 1, 0, 4, 1)
                self.grid.addWidget(self.buttons)              
            else:
                lbl.setPixmap(QPixmap(image).scaled(70, 70))
                self.grid.addWidget(lbl, i, 1, 1, 1)
                
    def onButton(self, tetx):                                                        # +++
        print(f'Вы кликнули кнопку -> {tetx}')


class ListWidget(QListWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ListWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setEditTriggers(self.NoEditTriggers)
        self.setFlow(self.LeftToRight)
        self.setWrapping(True)
        self.setResizeMode(self.Adjust)
        self.setSpacing(10)
        # Резиновая лента (для эффекта выбора рамки)
        self._rubberPos = None
        self._rubberBand = QRubberBand(QRubberBand.Rectangle, self)

    def makeItem(self, lb):
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(self)
        item.setSizeHint(QtCore.QSize(300, 300))
        self.setItemWidget(item, lb)


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('ListWidget')
        self.resize(1100, 670)
#        self.show()

        self.listWidget = ListWidget()

        # кнопка
        self.push_button = QPushButton('del 0 item')

        box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        # добавляем кнопку
        box.addWidget(self.push_button)

        box.addWidget(self.listWidget)

        self.urls = [
            "https://img.icons8.com/ios/452/phone.png",
            "https://img.icons8.com/ios/452/phone.png",
            "http://www.google.com/favicon.ico",
            "https://www.imgonline.com.ua/examples/random-pixels-wallpaper-big.jpg",
            "https://laguna-akul.ru/upload/003/u379/f4/61/8f68d93a.jpg",
        ]

        num = 5
        for i in range(num):
            art = Widget(self.urls, i)
            self.listWidget.makeItem(art)
            QApplication.processEvents()
        # связываем сигнал нажатия на кнопку с методом
        self.push_button.clicked.connect(self._on_push_button_clicked)

    # метод-обработчик кнопки
    def _on_push_button_clicked(self):
        # takeItem удаляет итем с виджетом из списка и возвращает его
        removed = self.listWidget.takeItem(0)
        print(removed)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я не знаю , как вы это делаете , но вы делаете это просто потрясающе. К сожалению GUI вознесся для меня высокой стеной , и мне ещё не скоро придётся столкнуться с ней снова , но я очень многое взял и для своего кода , спасибо ещё раз за всё.

Comment: @Leluch пожалуйста